# Embedding dynamic maps into PDF files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, javascript, pdf, tools, embeddable-web-maps

Working in consulting, I found that sending clients PDF file with my embedded maps is one of the best ways to achieve a wow-effect from them.

The latest pdf file formats all support the layers feature (which arcmap makes use of); however they also are able to support javascript.

Does anyone have ideas to use the power of javascript (or anything else) to make my maps within my pdf files more dynamic?

Which tools do you recommend? Any extensions to esri products?

Comment: If you have ArcGIS Desktop you have a named user account to use ArcGIS Online. Why not wow them by sharing the results to a web map and embedding into one of the configurable template apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If PDF supports Javascript, try [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/), see their [examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) of customization.

Answer (score 2):

I use terrago publisher. With the Terrago Edge solution they don't only use simple javascript embedding.
They have an entire application which from their website claims complete round trip gis data. mobile collection and collaboration. It sounds really interesting but is not open source.
[Terago Tech](http://www.terragotech.com/products/terrago-edge)

Comment: with GEO PDF, you go into each individual tract / parcel to edit in order to make that a pop-up, is that correct with the Terrago publisher?

Answer (score 2):

See also this question: [Adding interactive map to PDF?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/how-can-i-add-an-interactive-map-to-a-pdf)