# Making PDF exported from ArcMap have pop-up when clicking on feature?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, pdf

When converting your map into a PDF from ArcView 10.1, is there a way to make the PDF Map to have a pop-up when you click on a tract?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are several companies and products you can use: geoPDF is one of them.

There are much more detailed answers available at [Adding interactive map to PDF?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/how-can-i-add-an-interactive-map-to-a-pdf)

Comment: Have checked it out, with as much money we pay ESRI for any software etc... least they can do is build that function into the ArcGIS :)

Comment: http://ideas.arcgis.com/apex/ideaSearchResults?s=PDF&searchButton=search