# Geotagged HTML Pop in PDF

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, pdf, geotag, html-popup

I am using ArcGIS to add geotagged images as points to a map which allows me to click on the point and an HTML popup comes up with the photo.

http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0912/import-geotagged-photographs-into-arcmap.html

This works fine. What I would like to do, is export/print the map to a PDF and within the resulting PDF, I would like to be able to click on the points and get the same HTML popup. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

See this answer.
[Adding interactive map to PDF?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/adding-interactive-map-to-pdf)

This is not really possible within the constraints of the vanilla PDF file format.  These files are mostly static and have very limited opportunity for interaction.  Though it is possible to extend PDF functionalities with plugins, the users would have to have these plugins installed.  One other option would be to export the map to say, Google Maps, and then have an embedded flash control with that map loaded.  This requires your client to have flash and internet access.  Or manually you can use one of the paid versions of adobe acrobat to hyperlink points, one by one.

Using a PDF plugin is not unheard of and the most common would be any of the Geospatial PDF plugins/filetypes, of which there are a few with various levels of functionality, cost, and requirements for client software.  Most client software is free but the software to create the interactive maps you desire is usually not.